# keep renaming until file doesnt exist in directory

Tags: bash, file

I need to check if a file exists in a directory, if it does rename it by adding an extra extension like `original.txt` to `original.txt.txt`. BUT check whether the renamed file still exist.

My code only changes it one time and is not checking the rest of the contents before it renames it. It just overwrites all my `original.txt.txt`

Question:

How to check all files and add .txt as many times as needed so it doesn't conflict with any other name in directory.

```
if [ -e "$destination_folder/$basename_file" ]
     then
     cp "$file_name" "$destination_folder/$basename_file".txt
     fi
```

Comment: Can you include the code so far?

Comment: Are you sure adding stray copies of the extension is a good idea? Some software, such as Chrome running on Mac OS X, adds a number somewhere before the extension: `original.txt`, `original(1).txt`, etc., which tends to have better properties (the name doesn't get as ridiculously long), though the parentheses are designed not to make do it too often.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to rename a file only if there is no other file of the new name.  This you want to prevent accidental overwriting of this other file.

To achieve this you can use `mv` (which I assume you use for renaming) with the option `-i` so it will ask before overwriting anything.  In case you are quite sure you do not want to rename anything then, you can pipe `yes n` into the `mv` command:

```
yes n | mv -i "$old" "$new"
```

To prevent seeing ugly automatically answered questions, you can redirect the stderr of the commands to `/dev/null`:

```
(yes n | mv -i "$old" "$new") 2> /dev/null
```

This will now rename the file only if the new name is free.  Otherwise it does nothing.

EDIT:

You can use a loop to find a "free" name:

```
name=$original
while [ -e "$name" ]
do
  name="$name.txt"
done
mv "$original" "$name"
```

This way you will find a free name and then use it.

Be aware that this can still overwrite a just recently created file of the new name.  Unix systems are multitasking and another process could create a file of the new name just *after* the loop and *before* the `mv` command.

To avoid this pathological case (in case you cannot be sure that this won't happen), you should use my method above to move only if nothing would be overwritten, and afterwards you should check if the original file (with the original file name) still exists, and if it still exists, try the whole thing again:

```
new=$old.txt
while true
do
  (yes n | mv -i "$old" "$new") 2> /dev/null
  if [ -e "$old" ]
  then
    new=$new.txt
  else
    break
  fi
done
```

Comment: basicaly i have like for example 4 files all with the same name but with different content, i whant to copy from one directory to another, keeping the old name but addind one more extention... i added the part of the code that i have that only check for it once... it changes the original to original.txt.txt but then it just overwrites the original.txt.txt... i need it to keep adding .txt to the file. and with it being all automatic would be great with no prmpts

Comment: You also might want to have a look at the other features of the `mv` command.  It already can create backups of existing file, so maybe you'd just like to use this.