# Moving files in different folder changing the names

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a script to move some file in a common folder.
Basically I have n folders and in each of them there is a file called xmu.dat; I want to copy these files in a different folder changing its names.

This is the code I came up with (I have never written a script before...), but I get some errors:

```
echo "Folders found:"   
for folder in */
do
   echo "$folder"
   name = ${folder//[\/]/}
   cp ./"$folder"/xmu.dat ./OutputFiles/name
done
```

Comment: Can you print the errors you get?

Comment: what errors do you get? Consider pasting your code in http://www.shellcheck.net/ to see some (`name = ${...}` is wrong, for example, no spaces around `=`).

Comment: Thanks! The spaces were a first mistake. Now I don't get any error and it seems to work. Is there a way to check if a file exists before trying to copy it?

Comment: If you really cannot figure that out by googling, ask a separate question.  You will likely have that closed as a duplicate of an existing question, though.

Comment: ... such as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215220/keep-renaming-until-file-doesnt-exist-in-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As fedorqui said, the issue with your code is the presence of whitespaces around the '='.

If you want to check if a file exists, you can use the '-f' option, as:

```
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file found."
else
    echo "$file not found."
fi
```